# Is there any way to tell if someone is reading my iMessages?

Tags: messages

I think someone may be reading my iMessages on another device?  Is this possible?  Is there any way to find out?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: Not sure there's a way to know about this, but if you have a doubt, you'd better change your account password.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if somebody knows your AppleID password and uses it to log in onto another device. Changing the password and reviewing the list of alternative phone numbers/email addresses associated with your AppleID should be enough to resolve that (assuming that your new password is significantly better than the old).